# Save docker image and run in plesk

Tags: docker, plesk

how to build image, save as local file and run in docker on the vm server without using docker hub. I've tried save or export but every time I load or import image - no command found. I was searching few day in Google but didn't find any explanation. I tried simple blazor project say hello to make image using docker file and load into docker in plesk and run it. Can somebody help me with this problem .thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Run into Dockerfile directory:

```
docker build -t desire-docker-image-name:desire-docker-tag-name .
docker save -o desire-file-name.tar.gz desire-docker-image-name:desire-docker-tag-name
scp -i your-great-certificate your-user-on-remote-machine@remote-machine-ip:~
```

Open ssh connection to remote machine and run:

```
docker load -i desire-file-name.tar.gz
```

Your mission is done.

[docker build docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/)

[docker save docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/)

[docker load docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/)

[plesk docs](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001015213-How-to-install-upload-a-Docker-image-)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've created new blazor sample project and try run build but got error 'program does not contain a static method Main suitable for an entry point [/src/bll/bl1.csproj]'. But when I run that project from VS with docker image is created in docker and can run that image. But when use save command on that image and load to the remote server linux/plesk i have an error no command specify. Any idea ? Thank you for you time.

Comment: I have modify docker file and can build an image but when load to remote server always get error no message specified. It looks like there is no cmd or entrypoint in that image. But when I push to docker hub and later pull directly from docker to remote server that image is working. But I would like to build my image on my local pc and load on any server without docker hub. Is it possible ?